# Use UI Thread while asynctask is running

Tags: android, android-asynctask

I am updating my `UI` while `publishProgress()`, to be more explicit, I am updating my `RecyclerView` with songs that are taken from Cloud, while my list is updated I want to play a song or two but my broadcast is not sent to the `service` until `AsyncTask` is not finished but some features like `highlight` the song in `RecyclerView` and updating the UI works.

Is there a way how to send a `broadcast` while `async task` is running?

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you want to play a song returned from the cloud, maybe the first, once it ha been retrieved from the cloud.  Try using a Handler to send the song you want to play back to the UI thread.

Add code like this to your activity:

```
Handler handler = new Handler() {
      @Override
      public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
          // Play song based on message
         }
     };
```

Then in your publishProgress method send a Message like so:

```
Message msg = handler.obtainMessage();
Bundle b = new Bundle();
b.putString("message", "value you need");
msg(b);    
sendMessage(msg)
```

Answer (score 0):

I have solved my problem by forcing the `asynctask` to run in parallel with the method `executeOnExecutor()`